# Connection refused using PhantomJs

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I use Selenium + PhantomJS driver in python. It configures likes this:

```
desired_cap = {
        'phantomjs.page.settings.loadImages' : False,
        'phantomjs.page.settings.resourceTimeout' : 10000,
        'phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent' : '...'
}

self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=desired_cap)

self.driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
```

Than in cycle I request some pages using:

```
self.driver.get('page-url')
```

Everything works great for about 5 minutes (~1 get in 2 seconds), after that time I get error:

```
 <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
```

And it appears not only for get method, but for any method called from `self.driver`. I think that connection to `phantomjs` instance drops for some reason and object fails to send commands to it.

```
phantomjs --version
2.0.1-development

uname -a
Linux wincode 3.16.0-38-generic #52~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 8 09:43:57 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Everything is running on local machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that problem was in [memory leak of PhantomJS](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12903) when loading images is disabled:

```
'phantomjs.page.settings.loadImages' : False
```

So when I enabled images loading problem disappeared.